# Redux proper send of payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux. And I'm trying to create a simple `FETCH_ALL_POSTS`.

**actions**

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');
    console.log(response.data)
    dispatch({
       type: FETCH_ALL_POSTS,
       payload: response.data
    })
}
```

**posts reducer**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
const { type, payload } = action;
switch (type) {
    case FETCH_ALL_POSTS:
        return {
            ...state, payload
        }
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

**post list component**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
console.log(Object.values(state.posts))
return {
    posts: state.posts
}
}
```

This is working but the data that I'm getting from `mapStateToProps` is not what I'm expecting.

**Result** : "array: [ 0:[{},{},{}] ]"

**My expected result**: "array:[{},{},{}]"

Comment: Did you check the response data format?

Comment: Yes its an array of object

Comment: What is `jsonPlaceholder`?

Comment: Also can you show your combineReducer function?

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    const initialState = {
      posts: '',

    }
    export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case FETCH_ALL_POSTS:
            return{
                posts:state.posts=action.payload.posts
           }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```